# Original Domain Names VS Generic Ones ? (seo)

Tags: search, dns, search-engine, seo

We've currently a debate here about original domain names versus generic domain names in term of seo efficiency.

We mean by generic domain names, domains like :

```
- buy-hifi.com
- game-news.com
- easy-meet.com
```

We mean by original domain names, domains like :

```
- hifihot.com
- gamesmaniac.com
- lovein.com
```

What is your opinion ? (actually it's more a poll than a actual question but developments are welcome)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I remember reading an article about AccuWeather being offered the chance to buy weather.com.  They passed on it because it didn't reflect their image, The Weather Channel snatched it afterwards, and AccuWeather ended up regretting their decision.  While a generic name won't sing your brand, and a brand is important, it's hard to say which is better.  I couldn't imagine generic domain names for companies like Apple, Microsoft, IBM, etc., so I suppose it depends.  What a lousy answer.  How about this: both.  Why not have both name types and offer redirection?

Comment: yeah I agree, but you still have to choose which is the main one :)

Comment: OK, how about this.  I'll vote for generic because if you're trying to build a brand the generic type is easier to remember.